How to mock imported express middleware with jest and using supertest?
I have tests using supertest to connect to a server and I am trying to mock an authentication and an authorisation middlewares with Jest. I have found couple other questions which answers I have tried to combine this question is about mocking an imported function and then there are couple questions about mocking an express middleware: this, this one and also this
I have tried to combine the answers in those questions and came up with this
// server.ts
import express from 'express';
import { authentication } from 'auth-lib'

const server = express();

server.use(express.json());
server.use(authentication);
server.use('/someRoute', someRouter);

export { server };

// someRoute.test.ts
import { Server } from 'http';
import request from 'supertest';
import { server } from '../path/to/server'


describe('Some tests', () => {
  let app: Server;

  beforeAll(done => {
    app = server.listen(3210, done)
  });


  afterAll(done => {
    app.close(() => done())
  });

  it('POST someRoute', async () => {
    /**
     * Mocking the authentication middleware
     */
    jest.mock('auth-lib', () => ({
      __esModule: true,
      authentication: (req, res, next): void => {
        res.locals.authentication = { auth: true, authToken: 'asdasasd' };
        next();
      }
    }));
    /**
     * But it doesn't work
     */

    const res = await request(app)
      .post('/someRoute')
      .send(testData);

    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
  });
});

This doesn't seem to work. I have had some logging in the mocked middleware and the execution doesn't seem ever even go in there. I have also had some other variants of the mock, but these don't work either
jest.mock('auth-lib', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  authentication: jest.fn((req, res, next): void => {
    res.locals.authentication = { auth: true, authToken: 'asdasasd' };
    next();
  })
}));

jest.mock('auth-lib', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  authentication: jest.fn().mockImplementation((req, res, next): void => {
    res.locals.authentication = { auth: true, authToken: 'asdasasd' };
    next();
  })
}));

What is the correct way to mock the middlewares so that the res object is also extended and passed forward in the middleware chain?

jest.mock() only works in module scope. And you don't need pass the factory function, let it

Mocks a module with an auto-mocked version when it is being required. factory and options are optional

Then, you can provide difference mock implementation in each test case.
auth-lib.ts:
export const authentication = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('real implementation');
};

server.ts:
import express from 'express';
import { authentication } from './auth-lib';

const server = express();

server.use(express.json());
server.use(authentication);
server.post('/someRoute', (req, res) => {
  console.log('res.locals.authentication: ', res.locals.authentication);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

export { server };

someRoute.test.ts:
import request from 'supertest';
import { server } from './server';
import { authentication } from './auth-lib';

jest.mock('./auth-lib');

const authenticationmock = jest.mocked(authentication);

describe('Some tests', () => {
  it('POST someRoute', async () => {
    authenticationmock.mockImplementation((req, res, next) => {
      res.locals.authentication = { auth: true, authToken: 'asdasasd' };
      next();
    });
    const res = await request(server).post('/someRoute');
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
  });
});

Test result:
  console.log
    res.locals.authentication:  { auth: true, authToken: 'asdasasd' }

      at log (stackoverflow/78639299/server.ts:9:11)

 PASS  stackoverflow/78639299/someRoute.test.ts (8.62 s)
  Some tests
    √ POST someRoute (38 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        19.408 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

package versions:
"express": "^4.19.2",
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"supertest": "^7.0.0",


I have been trying this out, but for some reason I am getting mockImplementation is not a function error.

Ahhh never mind. I forgot the actual module mock jest.mock('auth-lib') part

Well actually there are some weird things happening. I guess I need to edit my post to give some additional info

Okay. This sort of works. I realised that I need to follow the docs explaining how to mock partials https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials
However. There's still another issue that I can't mock the  middleware per test, because in the server code the authorization is called once and in the tests the server is created only once. So either I need to find another way to inject some customised data into the middleware or recreate the server in every test

You might want to restructure your application to allow for injecting your middleware, like:
//createServer.js

import express from 'express';
import { authentication } from 'auth-lib'

// if middleware parameter is not provided, uses the defaults
export function createServer(middleware = [express.json(), authentication]){
    const server = express(); 
    middleware.forEach((v) => {
        express.use(v);
    });

    
    server.use('/someRoute', someRouter); // or similarly inject routes
    return server
}

export {createServer};


Now, in your tests you can just instantiate your middleware with whatever you want:
describe('Some tests', () => {
  let app: Server;

  beforeAll(done => {
    let server = createServer([(req, res, next) => {
       // your mock implementation here
    }]); 
    app = server.listen(3210, done)
  });



Very interesting and simple approach! I never even thought of that. Even though for the sake of the question I would like to get the mocks work I might still try this out. With this there wouldn't even be need for any jest mocks

@zaplec " With this there wouldn't even be need for any jest mocks " exactly. IMO Avoid module mocking if you can. The jest.fn function is still useful to make assertions that your function is being called. Module mocks can be helpful for testing and refactoring existing code.

I tried this and it works to certain extent. But yet I haven't figured out how I could change the auth data set to res.locals in each test. If I set it once when initially injecting the mock mw to server, then all the tests would have same data in them

That's the reason why I was going for mocks in the first place. I could clear the mocks after every test if need be and the recreate the mock with correct test data where needed
